# How to keep cursor fixed in a React input box that updates state onChange?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

Whenever I try to change the words in the input box, for example clicking on 3000 to change it to 8080, whenever I type a letter out the cursor brings me to the end of the inputbox. I'm assuming this is happening because my state changes whenever I try to change the input value, and the default thing to do is bring the cursor to the end of the value. Do you have any suggestion on how to fix this?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Example() {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState("http://localhost:3000");

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={url} onChange={(e) => setUtl(e.target.value)} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `setUtl` be `setUrl`?

Comment: I copied your code into a CodeSandbox and it works like it should. All I did was change setUtl to setUrl: https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-fast-rj66y